# Why isn't implode adding string to array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, implode

I have this section of code but for some reason the comma isn't being added to separate the array elements. What am I overlooking?

```
    $imgid = array();

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $imgid[] = $attachment->ID;
  //    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    }

    $string = implode(',', $imgid);

    echo $string;
```

The above foreach code is located in a larger foreach statement:

```
foreach ($fileslist as $file) {

    if( $file === '.' || $file === '..' ) {
        continue;
    }

    $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/" . $file);

    $filetype = "image/jpeg";

    $filename = "remote_filename_". $i .".jpg";

    $i++;


    xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
    $params = array($blogid,$username,$password,
                array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);

    $result = go($request,$rpcurl);
    print_r($result);

    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ));

    $imgid = array();

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $imgid[] = $attachment->ID;
  //    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    }


    $comma_separated = implode(",", $imgid);

    echo $comma_separated;

}
```

Basically, what this does is it takes each image in a directory and uploads it to WordPress. There is an attachment ID for each image and I am needing to get each attachment ID saved as a string with each ID separated by a comma.

Edit: Simon Robb provided the correct answer for me. Here is updated and final code:

```
foreach ($fileslist as $file) {

    if( $file === '.' || $file === '..' ) {
        continue;
    }

    $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/" . $file);

    $filetype = "image/jpeg";

    $filename = "remote_filename_". $i .".jpg";

    $i++;


    xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
    $params = array($blogid,$username,$password,
                array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);

    $result = go($request,$rpcurl);
    print_r($result);

    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        // 'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ));

    $imgid = array();

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
         $imgid[] = $attachment->ID;
  //    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    }


    echo "<br />";
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $imgid);

}

echo $comma_separated;
```

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but is this really your code, or is it simplified? That is, are you using `,` as the separator in your real code, not something like `\n` or `<br/>`?

Comment: Do a `print_r($imgid);` right after the loop.

Comment: Ed, that is correct. I am using a comma as a separator. I need to build a string that has the returned numbers separated by a comma. I am very inexperienced with PHP, is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What is the `echo` actually outputting? Is it all the IDs concatenated without the commas, or an empty string?

Comment: It's the IDs concatenated without the commas.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem - can you do a `var_dump($imgid)` just before your `implode` and let us know what the output is?

Comment: Here is the var_dump($imgid) output: array(1) { [650]=> int(650) } 
array(1) { [651]=> int(651) } 
array(1) { [652]=> int(652) } 
array(1) { [653]=> int(653) }

Comment: Okay cool - `implode` wants a single array, rather than a bunch of single-element arrays like what you've got there. It might be that `$attachment->ID` is returning an array instead of the scalar you're expecting, try `$imgid[] = is_array($attachment->ID) ? reset($attachment->ID) : $attachment->ID` instead, to pick up if it's an array.

Comment: Ok, so when I do that, I get array(1) { [0]=> int(670) } 
array(1) { [0]=> int(671) } 
array(1) { [0]=> int(672) } 
array(1) { [0]=> int(673) } Also, the results of implode is that each ID is returned on a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on how your code is intended to work, but currently each `$file` in your `$filelists` loop is only returning one attachment, because of the `'posts_per_page' => 1` parameter in `get_posts`. Therefore the `$imgid` variable only ever has one element, so `implode` doesn't have two element to put the comma between.

The output you're seeing is actually one `ID` being outputted for each loop of `$filelist`.

If you remove the `'posts_per_page' => 1` parameter, you'll have the full array of attachments in `$attachments` and it should work fine.

Comment: Yep, that's it, thanks! I updated the final OP with the fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is sound & should work as expected. But without seeing your larger codebase it is hard to tell what is happening. My only guess is there is a larger loop in play & your initing of `$imgid` is reseting the array each iteration:

```
$imgid = array();
```

Is it possible for you to place that array init higher up in your logic? If so, try that to see what happens. And maybe assiging the index key with the `$attachment->ID` would help:

```
$imgid = array();

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $imgid[$attachment->ID] = $attachment->ID;
//    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
}
```

Comment: You are correct, The foreach that I put in the OP is inside of a larger foreach. When I set the array outside of the original foreach, the result is 596596,597596,597,598596,597,598,599 when it should be 596,597,598,599. The result numbers are different in the answer below because they represent uploaded images. Each time images are uploaded the numbers change. That doesn't really have anything to do with the foreach though...just fyi.

Comment: Yes, it's for a WordPress website. I updated the OP with the complete foreach statement. The original foreach is located in other foreach.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still returns the same results. The IDs are returned by not separated by a comma.